# React.js on App Engine as a service querying an API running as another service on same project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, proxy

The React.js front-end is running as the default service on `project-id.appspot.com`.

It is querying an API running on `API-dot-project-id.appspot.com`.

I know proxy settings in package.json only work in development. Using the absolute URL of the API causes CORS issues.

What the best way to resolve this?

**Here's what I tried.**

I added the following the my backend API service app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /api/(.*)
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://project-id.appspot.com
```

Now I am getting the following error when trying to deploy:

```
Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap
    secure=default
    static_files=None
    application_readable=None
    auth_fail_action=redirect
    require_matching_file=None
    static_dir=None
    redirect_http_response_code=None
    http_headers={u'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://project-id.appspot.com'}
    url=/api/(.*)
    script=None
    upload=None
    api_endpoint=None
    expiration=None
    position=None
    login=optional
    mime_type=None
    >
```

Comment: Serve the frontend from the same domain as the API ... or ... enable CORS for the API ... or ... serve your React from a proxy that routes data requests to the API.

Comment: I added my app.yaml edit and the resulting error.

Comment: You're missing the handler type, i.e. the `script` or `static_dir`/`static_file` statement for your hander.

Comment: So, it looks like http_headers cannot be set for an API, its only for static files? Is that right?

Comment: `http_headers` in app.yaml can only be set for responses of your static file or directory handlers. If you need to set HTTP headers in your `script` handlers, you should instead do that in your app's code. This is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element

Comment: Looks like that is an option for Python but not for Node.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way to bypass your issue with the same-origin policy is to create (or update) your project's [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref) file to route API requests to the API service, through the default domain of `project-id.appspot.com`.

Then you don't have to worry about same-origin issues between your frontend and your API because they're all served from the same domain, even though they're running as separate App Engine services. This approach has spared me a lot of trouble when dividing an application into multiple services.

Your `dispatch.yaml` file would look something like this:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: API
```

Then your frontend at `project-id.appspot.com` can simply make requests to `https://project-id.appspot.com/api/*`, and those requests will be routed to the API service.

Comment: Thank you. The dispatch.yaml file would be for the default (front-end) service?

Comment: There is only one `dispatch.yaml` per project, and [it can be deployed independently of other code/configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref#deploying_the_dispatch_configuration_file), much like `cron.yaml` and `queue.yaml`. App Engine's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#creating_a_dispatch_file) recommends "The dispatch file should be placed either in the root of your project directory, or in the root directory of your `default` service", though I think that's just a convention.